# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, php-7

**Magneto 1.9.3 moved to new server with PHP version 7.0.23**

I updated my Magento website server to a new PHP version; it's now 7.0.23, but before that it was working fine. Now it's giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be an instance of
> Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in

[image]

I tried inchoo patch for php 7 also but nothing work.
https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: That line in particular reads `public function setWebsite(Mage_Core_Model_Website $website)` - to accept `null` in PHP 7 that would have to declare that `$website` is nullable (e.g. `setWebsite(Mage_Core_Model_Website $website = null)`. Has the Inchoo patch installed correctly? Magento 1.9x isn't actually PHP7 compatible out of the box.

Comment: yes patch installed correctly @CD001

Comment: @CD001 your reference helps a lot thanks...

Comment: also check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214205/error-with-store-id-for-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the method mentioned by [@cd001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886824/cd001) in a comment:

First I updated file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store/Group.php`. In that file I just replaced the below line:

```
public function setWebsite(Mage_Core_Model_Website $website)
```

with

```
public function setWebsite(Mage_Core_Model_Website $website = null)
```

Then I got another error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in 
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 Stack trace: #0 
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #1 
app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() #2 
app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') #3 
app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') #4 
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction() #5 
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index') #6 
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 555
```

For that I updated the file: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php`. In that file, I replaced the below line:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

with

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

and everything works fine now.

Comment: I suggest you  to update app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store/Group.php in a local override / module. When you update your Magento again this change will potentially be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like current release of Inchoo_PHP7 only works with most recent version of Magento. Read their release notes https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/releases

My older version of Inchoo_PHP7 contains all fixes for files you mentioned above. like this one...

```
<core>
    <rewrite>
        <layout>Inchoo_PHP7_Model_Layout</layout>
    </rewrite>
</core>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

AND

CLEAR CACHE! (remove all in magento/var/chache/)